# Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B ( Issue was different as you may see the resolution is different)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, struts2

I am trying to learn Hibernate-Spring-Struts using the example [Struts 2 + Spring + Hibernate integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/).

But after creating the `pom.xml` getting this error :

```
Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B
```

I made a progress only up to creating the `pom.xml` file and made the changes to include most recent libraries.

**Here is my `pom.xml`:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>S3HMaven</groupId>
<artifactId>S3HMaven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>S3HMaven</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1B</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Struts 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Struts 2 + Spring plugins -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.15.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate core library dependency start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate core library dependency end -->

    <!-- Hibernate query library dependency start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate query library dependency end -->

</dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried with and without dependency for `javax.transation`. Did not make difference. Can any one tell me what am I doing wrong ? What should I do to get rid of it?

Comment: changed pom to 1.1 instead of 1.0.1B, works better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error in your `pom.xml` because you mess up different versions of Struts core and plugins.

Change

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know why do you need JTA 1.0.1B but you could change hibernate to 3.3.2 (at least, without headaches)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.ga</version>
</dependency>
```

it has a recommended dependency for JTA 1.1.

Create a new project from `pom.xml` then add source files to it.

Comment: I had to change it to 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
to get it work

Answer (score 28):

In my case i tried example from mkyong

[jsf-2.0 spring hibernate integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/)

When i got the exception i searched alot i was using spring sts suit tool , and eclipse MARS with JDK 8 the **solution was**

I changed pom to **1.1** instead of **1.0.1B**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And if it could not be downloaded automatically from m2 repo you should download it manualy (you can check this in the repo in folder `C:\Users\pc1\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar` )

and check the maven dependency in project properties it should not give you an error in the lib tab.

**References :**
[reference 1](https://snipt.net/belano/missing-artifact-javaxtransactionjtajar101bcompile/)
[reference 2](http://blog.dawouds.com/2008/11/missing-indirectly-referenced-artifact.html)
[reference 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003298/missing-javax-transaction-jta-artifact)
[reference 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285831/maven-missing-dependency-jta-1-0-1b)
[reference 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696805/java-repository-of-eclipse-with-maven-missing-artifactcompile)

**Related issues might appear after you solve this if you are applying the tutorial:**

1-http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/

2-http://jonathan.lalou.free.fr/?p=2026

3-[Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144975/error-creating-bean-with-name-sessionfactory-unable-to-instantiate-default-tup)
[Tomcat error: Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915020/tomcat-error-not-found-in-externalcontext-as-a-resource)

Answer (score 6):

Which repository are you using?

Add the [java.net](http://download.java.net/maven/2/) Maven repository as below.

```
<repository>
    <id>java.net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Please refer below link . i was getting same issue and it resolve my error .    http://www.coderanch.com/t/532379/tools/Maven-find-artifact-javax-transaction

Answer (score 2):

This repo worked for me:

```
   <repository>
           <id>webpublico-repository</id>
                <name>Webpublico Nexus Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.webpublico.com.br/repository/maven-public/</url>
   </repository>
```

Answer (score 1):

some approach from [Unable to resolve javax.transaction dependency](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/QtEcVoMb0Po)

clear the .ivy/cache folder. it works, **but takes very long time**.

Comment: vote up for the try, any way, if you delete the .m2/repository path, its download anyway from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/ and that repoo don't has the jar file as expected... :(

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it may be unnecessary. But I think we should update this ticket for someone.

It works for me. Change porm.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```